# How to get the full GitHub URL of a commit?

Tags: git, github

I currently have this command which is cumbersome:

```
echo https://github.com/$(git remote -v | grep -oP ':\K.*?(?=.git)' | head -n1)/commit/$(git rev-parse HEAD) 
> commit-url.txt
```

Would it be possible to make it simpler?

Comment: Can you show `git config remote.origin.url` output? It's hard to know what effects are important here.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [github cli](https://cli.github.com/) might make things easier:

```
echo "$(gh repo view --json url  --jq .url)/commit/$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```